# How to Initialize a Register of Vectors?

Tags: chisel

I have defined a register of vectors like this

```
val my_reg = Reg(Vec(n, Bits(32.W)))
```

and I access the elements of this register in a for loop using `my_reg(i)`.

Now, I like to initialize this register to zero, so I change the variable definition to this

```
val my_reg = Reg(Vec(n, Bits(32.W)), init = UInt(0))
```

However, I get the following compilation error when I want to access the elements of this register

```
chisel3.core.Data does not take parameters
my_reg(i) := io.a(i)
```

How can I define a register of vectors and properly initialize them synchronously?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use RegInit instead.  I believe the following statement will do what you want

```
    val my_reg = RegInit(Vec(Seq.fill(n)(0.U(32.W))))
```

The Vector is initialized by a Seq of UInt zeros that are 32 bits wide

Comment: Thanks a lot. You just need to add another right parenthesis at the end.

Comment: You may also want to remove "that are". It's written twice. I can't edit your solution.

Comment: I am new to Chisel and Scala -- it looks like Seq.fill is a Scala function that creates an "array" of elements -- however, I'm not familiar with "0.U(32.W)" syntax, could someone explain the mechanics of the syntax? (I get that it defines a UInt whose value is zero -- but the details of the syntax mechanics are foreign and I can't find where in the Scala or Chisel manual to look -- no real keywords to search for this)  Thanks!

Comment: 0.U(32.W) means the value zero as a unsigned hardware integer, that is 32bits wide.

Comment: Change Vec to VecInit because of the following:

`Warning:(235, 34) method do_apply in object Vec is deprecated (since chisel3): Vec(elts) is deprecated, use VecInit(elts) instead
  val loadEnableReg = RegInit(Vec(Seq.fill(config.LoadersNum)(0.U)))`

Answer (score 5):

Looks like in Chisel 3 this should be `VecInit` instead of `Vec`:

```
val initRegOfVec = RegInit(VecInit(Seq.fill(4)(0.U(32.W))))
```

Source: https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/wiki/Cookbook#how-do-i-create-a-reg-of-type-vec